# How to change an image location in jupyter?

Tags: python

i have this dataset where extracted the hyperlinks for images. I created a dictionary of just the hyperlinks . I m using pillow i python for image processing . I m trying to save the images but i want to change the location of images and want them to be saved in a specific folder.

Thanks!!

Comment: have you looked into [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)? This can move files and there are many uses in the documentation

Comment: The `save` methods in `Pillow` should take full paths (eg `/path/to/desired/imagedirectory`) as arguments

Comment: Awesome , it worked !! Thanks Adam